# Solr - Field aliasing when using pivot facets

Tags: solr, facet

I would like to know if there is an option to rename the fields that return when using the facet.pivot method.
I tried using the {!key=my_alias}fieldname - didn't work
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solr doesn't support renaming the fields returned by a pivot facet, but you can rename the pivot facet itself:

`facet.pivot={!key=product}make,model`